# Error while trying to config camel https sink connector in kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I am using the amq streams operator on openshift which is based on strimzi operator. I have a kafka cluster and kafka connect and I want to send every log that comes to the kafka cluster to an https endpoint. Therefore I am using the camel https sink connector. I have basic configuration which includes the endpoint url, the topic and the key and value converters. However I keep getting the error "can't find valid certificate path to request target".

This is the connector configuration:

camel.sink.endpoint.httpMethod: POST

camel.sink.path.htypUri: [endpoint path]

key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.stringconverter

value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.stringconverter

topics: [my topic]

Comment: This kind of error normally suggest that the HTTP server you are connecting to is using a server certificate which your connector doesn't trust. So you would need to either change the HTTP server to use some server certificate signed by a public CA such as Let's Encrypt. Or you would need to configure the trusted certificates of the connector and make the CA used by the HTTP server trusted. But I have no idea if the connector supports it or not.

Comment: The http server is using a certificate signed by a public ca and because I set the tls on the kafka connect and I am still getting the error I suspect that the error caused by the connector which doesn't recognize the certificate

Comment: If it is a recognized public CA, you should not need to configure it in Kafka Connect. But in any case, Connect is not responsible for the connection between the connector and the HTTP server. This is solely the responsibility of the connector itself.

Comment: That what I'm trying to do. But I don't know how to configur this connector to trust the http server. This is the documentation: https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/3.18.x/reference/connectors/camel-https-kafka-sink-connector.html I couldn't find anything useful in it

Comment: It will be noisy but you can add:

```
  jvmOptions:
    javaSystemProperties:
      - name: javax.net.debug
        value: all
```

To your KafkaConnect configuration to get logs about problems connecting

Comment: Is there any way to check where the connector is looking for certificates?